# Using Promise.all() in WebdriverIO

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, automated-tests, webdriver-io

I have this problem when trying to execute this block of code for each of the categories of an array, which works when not needing to use `Promise.all()` to handle only one category. When executing tests, something seems to be missing because I get an error (see below).

```
await Promise.all(categories.map(async category => {

  // Upload file
  await orderPage.uploadFile(`data/${fileName}`);
  // Open Category dropdown menu
  await orderPage.clickElement(await orderPage.categoryMenu);
  // Select category
  await orderPage.categorySearchBar.setValue(category.name);
  await browser.keys('Enter');

}));
```

`uploadFile()` method:

```
async uploadFile(filePath) {

const remoteFilePath = await browser.uploadFile(filePath);

await browser.execute(() => {

  document.querySelector('input[type=file]').style.display = 'block';

});

await this.inputFile.setValue(remoteFilePath);
```

}

This is the error I get:
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DthSe.png)